# Moving jquery code to external file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to move jquery code from internal html file to external file and link it in the head of html file, the site is working inside html but when I move the code to external file the link is not working.

HTML head code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/newsite/style.css" title="new" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Most likely reason is that you got the URL wrong. Debug it using the Net tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Please share how and where you added your js

Comment: And where have you included the jquery file?

Comment: I updated my question I included html file and js file, I hope this will help

Comment: You need to load jQuery before you use it. You are trying to use jQuery before you loaded it via `<script>`. If that does not fix it make sure you directories are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

You are trying to use jQuery before you loaded the jQuery library. You need to switch these around like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>
```

Although I don't recommend getting the latest jQuery, you never know what may be deprecated in the future.

If that does not fix the problem make sure you directories are the correct ones. Check the console on your browser for error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out before your post, but I marked your question correct, thank you very much

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake. I mentioned it in a comment and decided to answer to clarify. And thank you for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome, press F12 to open Dev Tools and click on the "console" tab.  Then refresh the page. You should see some sort of error as to why your script is not working.

If there is no error, click the "network" tab and look for your JavaScript file.  Any files loaded into the page should show up here.  If if isn't there, it wasn't loaded, which means you haven't properly added the script tag to your HTML.

Comment: I know you don't have the rep to comment yet, but this isn't an answer. It's a helpful comment on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Doesn't that mean this isn't a real question?  The question really is just asking us to troubleshoot, because something is just "not working".  These are the steps one should take to get it to work. I am not arguing - just trying to clarify and understand.

Comment: No, it's a real question, maybe not a hall of fame question, but still. The error the OP is getting is missing from his question and is what would really enable us to answer.

Comment: Sorry electricity went off for 10 minutes, I have Firefox, the code is not working, it only work if I included the full code inside html file

Comment: j08691, I think I understand.  Thanks.  Khali, your problem is with the dot at the beginning of the path.  It means you are linking inside the current directory.  It needs to be "/newsite/js/scripting.js" with no dot, just a slash at the beginning.  The slash alone will link from the root directory of your site.  If you include the dot, the path gets repeated.

Comment: I remove the dot but also not working

Comment: What is the error message?  Follow the instructions in my answer to open tools and paste the error.  It should work in Firefox as well, I think you need to open firebug.  It is very difficult to help you if we cannot see your error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this from a local HTML file, I'm pretty confident your problem is the file isn't being included.

The code to include it should *probably* be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>
```

**or**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>
```

But just starting with a backslash means the current domain's root. Which, if you're running the file locally, will be your C drive (*probably*).

*I say probably because you haven't given much to go on.*

Comment: I included the file and it shows in my question, but the code is not working, thanks

Comment: I know you wrote code to include the file, but if you're running the file locally I guarantee you that it hasn't actually been included for the reasons I explained above.

Comment: The file is not running locally, it is live site, the code I place above works only when I included inside html file, but when I move it out it is not working

Comment: Can you link us to the live site please. You need to provide more information if you want this to be resolved. Moving working JS to an external file will not stop it from working - there is clearly some other issue you're having.

Comment: here is the site: http://khaleha3rbi.com/newsite/

Comment: The code should work when I click on "Create Arabic Fonts" line

Comment: You are getting the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://khaleha3rbi.com/newsite/newsite/js/scripting.js which means it's not being included.

Comment: I updated my question I included html file and js file, I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Place a **console.log();** at the bottom of your script, load your page with the developer tools console open, if you can see your log your script is running, there may be another external JavaScript file or an internal script that is interfering with your script which is stopping it from working, check to see what scripts you have loading in the  of your page, have the script that's not working loaded at the bottom of the page so the script is already loaded when the page loads.

Your source directory could be wrong also, when you load your page open up the developer tools and select 'console' to check if you have an error that the file could not be found.

*edit

The console is showing: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

This is the link:http://khaleha3rbi.com/newsite/newsite/js/scripting.js

You need to **remove** one of the "newsite" folders in that directory link.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, the solution was to switch between to lines in the `<head>` tag.

it was like that:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

I make it:
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/newsite/js/scripting.js"></script>`

and it works.

Thank you all for help